# Visual Studio Code автоматически закрывает одиночные тэги после сохранения

Tags: html, веб-программирование, visual-studio-code, prettier

В общем у меня в visual studio code стоит prettier. Но не могу разобраться как решить проблему. При нажатии ctrl + s (сохранение файла) у меня html код автоматически форматируется и одиночные тэги такие как `<img>`, `<br>` форматируются в `<img \>`, `<br \>` что не совсем корректно. Как это можно изменить?

Comment: у меня ничего не стоит (prettier), но этот тег всегда выводится со слешом, и это допустимо. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946426/html-5-is-it-br-br-or-br //p.s. только у вас слеш не так стоит <br />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как подсказал Dev18 в целом нет разницы в `<br>` и `<br />`. Поэтому не критично, что IDE автоматически пишет `<br />`. А валидатор помечает это не как ошибку, а как warning, что в целом не плохо.